# Minimum size for image upload

Tags: image, uploads

I know that one can set a maximum size (in pixels) for images uploaded through the CP, but is there any way to set a *minimum* size? (Ideally without buying a complete image manipulation suite like CE Images, since this is a low budget site and this is the only feature I'd need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a free solution but Photo Frame will do what you're after. https://objectivehtml.com/photo-frame/settings

Comment: In the end Andrew I worked around the problem from a different direction, circumventing the resize issue entirely. But Photo Frame looks good, and I'll be bookmarking that for later reference. Cheers.

Comment: Hi Rick, how did you approach it in the end? Could you post as an answer please?

Comment: Not sure I should post it as an 'answer', because it isn't. But I took an entirely different (all-native) approach to the design challenge I had and found a way to reuse the existing image sizes that already existed in the database, even if they were smaller than I would like. However, the change of approach was significant enough that, TBH, I don't think my final solution still falls within the scope of the original question. Suffice to say that I did away with needing a minimum size by means of changing the page design.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on how you are going to use this. File upload with a Channel Form or via a WYSIWYG editor. However both these examples don't have a straight forward configuration but you could write a conditional with a minimum file size.

CE-image will perform practically any image manipulation you can think of, but it also cannot set an minimum upload size for the original file.

If you wish to avoid conditionals I am sure this can also be done with Javascript.

Comment: Hi Nutmeg. The images would be uploaded via a straightforward File field in the CP. By conditionals I assume you mean setting a minimum size in the template, but I'd prefer to handle the issue before it reaches that stage -- i.e. at upload. Same goes for javascript. But thanks for chiming in.